# How can I make elbows and knees on this without distorting the texture?

Tags: rendering, texturing, armature

This is my model:
[image: The Textured Character]
<sub>(source: [ezimba.com](http://www.ezimba.com/work/150814C/ezimba15546414651300.png))</sub>

It has two triangular vertices on the front of the arm.
[image: Vertices]
<sub>(source: [ezimba.com](http://www.ezimba.com/work/150814C/ezimba15546411412200.png))</sub>

How can I change the number of vertices to allocate for the texture without distorting it?

[My .blend file.](https://www.mediafire.com/file/bkrgm45wo6pc375/My_Model_and_Textures.zip/file)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to transform the tris in quads, or you'll not be able to make loopcuts.

[image]

[image]

Than make loopcuts in the elbow position with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

[image]

What is important is to check the **Correct UVs** option in the command option panel. This will prevent distortion while working with the new edgeloops.

[image]

Same thing when you slide them

[image]

[image]

Comment: It forces me to place one at the middle, how did you duplicate and spread from the middle? And how did you get a texture map to appear?

Comment: I started by placing one in the middle, than I slided it down (double press G). You can increase the number of loopcuts by rolling the mousewheel. About the texture map.. You mean how to open the UV/Image editor? See:https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/UV_Map_Basics

Comment: I did what you said exactly, and what the wiki said, and when I bent the arm the half with his hand wound up shrinking. How can I fix that so his arm will curve? instead of bending at a straight angle and shrinking the tip?

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out what is the part that has been shrinked. Can you add a screenshot of the situation? And maybe a scketch of what you want to achieve..

Comment: The top is technically the player's shoulder, even though it has just bricks for arms. The part with the "wristband" that has a checkerboard is the bottom half, which is it's "hand" and the way it should render is have it curve at the back and bunch slightly at the front, like a person's elbow would.